# Python - object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking

When I was trying to mock an async function in unittest with MagicMock, I got this exception:

> TypeError: object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression

With sample code like:

```
# source code
class Service:
    async def compute(self, x):
        return x

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.service = Service()

    async def handle(self, x):
        return await self.service.compute(x)

# test code
import asyncio
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('__main__.Service')
    def test_handle(self, mock):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        app = App()
        res = loop.run_until_complete(app.handle('foo'))
        app.service.compute.assert_called_with("foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How should I fix it with built-in python3 libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock aiohttp.client.ClientSession.get async context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761985/how-to-mock-aiohttp-client-clientsession-get-async-context-manager)

Comment: I'm not using asynctest as a third party library. Is there any standard way to fix it without any external dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480108/mocking-async-call-in-python-3-5

Answer (score 38):

In python 3.8+ you can make use of the `AsyncMock`

```
async def test_that_mock_can_be_awaited():
   mock = AsyncMock()
   mock.x.return_value = 123
   result = await mock.x()
   assert result == 123
```

The class `AsyncMock` object will behave so the object is recognized as an async function, and the result of a call is an awaitable.

```
>>> mock = AsyncMock()
>>> asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(mock)
True
>>> inspect.isawaitable(mock())
True
```

Answer (score 27):

I ended up with this hack.

```
# monkey patch MagicMock
async def async_magic():
    pass

MagicMock.__await__ = lambda x: async_magic().__await__()
```

It only works for MagicMock, not other pre-defined return_value

Answer (score 12):

You can get mocks to return objects that can be awaited by using a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html). The following is a [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) test case, but something similar should be possible with [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

```
async def test_that_mock_can_be_awaited():
    mock = MagicMock(return_value=Future())
    mock.return_value.set_result(123)
    result = await mock()
    assert result == 123
```

In your case, since you're patching `Service` (which gets passed in as `mock`), `mock.return_value = Future()` should do the trick.

Comment: The solution works fine for me in Python 3.7. But it throw error like `AttributeError: '_asyncio.Future' object has no attribute '<sub-mocked-function>'` in Python 3.8.

Comment: Worked for me in Python 3.8.10 on Linux.

Comment: For users who are copying the code: you need to add `from asyncio import Future` to the import statements

Answer (score 12):

shaun shia provided really good universal solution, but i found what in python 3.8 you can use just `@patch('__main__.Service', new=AsyncMock)`

Comment: Thanks, searched everywhere for this!

Comment: This should be the correct answer! use `mock.AsyncMock`

Answer (score 6):

I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498408/8741356) very useful when trying to `await` a mock object in Python < 3.8. You simply create a child class `AsyncMock` that inherits from `MagicMock` and overwrites a `__call__` method to be a coroutine:

```
class AsyncMock(MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, inside your test, do:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_my_method():
    # Test "my_method" coroutine by injecting an async mock
    my_mock = AsyncMock()
    assert await my_method(my_mock)
```

you might also want to install [`pytest-asyncio`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a `pytest-mock` solution compatible with < py3.8, I did something like this.

```py
class AsyncMock(MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

def test_my_method(mocker):
    my_mock = mocker.patch("path.to.mocked.thing", AsyncMock())
    my_mock.return_value = [1, 2, 3]

    assert my_method()
```

Definitely borrowed from Tomasz's solution here!

Answer (score 0):

To override async classes one needs to tell `patch` that the `return_value` needs to be `AsyncMock`. So use

```
@patch('__main__.Service', return_value=AsyncMock(Service))
def test_handle(self, mock):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = App()
    res = loop.run_until_complete(app.handle('foo'))
    app.service.compute.assert_called_with("foo")
```

With that `Service` will be a `MagicMock`, but `Service()` will return an `AsyncMock` instance of `Service`.